# Deleting Rows from GridView

Tags: c#, silverlight, gridview, telerik

I have an `RadGridView`. When users clicks on a `row` and then click my `Delete` button I call a method to delete that row from my database. But it shows this entry on the `GridView`. I can manually call the `LoadGridView()` method again to show the user that the entry has been deleted but isn't there any other built-in method that can remove that item from the GridView too?

Here is the Delete Click EventHandler:

```
private void OnDeleteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Product deleteProduct = new Product();
    foreach (Product product in this.grdProductGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
        deleteProduct = product;
    }
    if (deleteProduct != null)
    {
        _service.DeleteProductAsync(deleteProduct);
        this.grdProductGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

The grid binding:

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = productList;
```

Comment: You probably need to remove the row from the model/viewmodel and it should be reflected right away. I doubt you want to remove the row from the gridview manually.

Comment: How will I remove that particular entry from the ItemsSource?

Comment: you need to add ScriptManager and UpdatePanel after adding this you put your gridview inside UpdatePanel. when you delete the data/row you need to load gridview again. I hope it is helpfull for you

Comment: @HumaAli What are you using for an ItemSource? A regular ObservableCollection? If so, there's a few Remove/RemoveAt/RemoveItem versions to call on it to remove an item.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Its a `List` (See my question). I tried the `Remove` method `((ObservableCollection<Product>)this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource).Remove(deleteProduct);` but got error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`

Comment: @HumaAli Try something like (the untested) `List tmp = (List)this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource; tmp.Remove(deleteP‌​roduct); this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = null; this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = tmp;`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Works! Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a `List` as a source, you need to remove the item from the list and manually force the `RadGridView` to refresh;

```
// Temporarily store the ItemSource as a List in tmp
List tmp = (List)this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource; 

// Remove the item from the List
tmp.Remove(deleteP‌​roduct); 

// Force a refresh by "tricking" RadGridView 
// that it's getting an entirely new ItemsSource
this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = null; 
this.grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = tmp;
```